# How do I select variable +/- 5 days between another variable using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write code to select diagnosis within 5 days of a drug start date in SQL.

Right now, I have it set up to select diagnosis within the study period:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT PatientSID,
DrugStartDate
DiagnosisDate
DiagnosisType
FROM #studycohort
WHERE DiagnosisDate >= '2017-10-01' AND DiagnosisDate <= '2019-09-30'
```

I think it should be something along the lines of this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT PatientSID,
DrugStartDate
DiagnosisDate
DiagnosisType
FROM #studycohort
WHERE DiagnosisDate + 5 days DrugStartDate AND DiagnosisDate - 5 days DrugStartDate
```

Of course, the `WHERE` command isn't right, but I am hopeful someone can help! Thank you!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, SQLite, etc? The options differ between them.

Comment: How you add/subtract intervals to/from dates depends on the SQL product (RDBMS) you are using, you have not tagged any (SQL is generic, you need to tag if you are using SqlServer, Oracle, PostGreSQL, etc.)

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help clarify your requirements.

Comment: Btw, "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" is an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). Your [dbms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) is Sql Server.  To find the version `SELECT @@Version`

Comment: Thank you - The version is Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU13)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, so the condition you most likely need is:

```
WHERE DiagnosisDate BETWEEN DATEADD(-5, DAY, DrugStartDate) AND DATEADD(5, DAY, DrugStartDate)
```

I'm not sure I understood your wording right, you might need to switch to look for DrugStartDate in between DiagnosisDate +/- 5 days.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, when I run this, it says that "datetime2 is compatible with int". Do you know of a solution I should look into for that?

Comment: So that was a poor suggestion. Do NOT use mathematical operators with date or any other related datatype. Use the DATEADD function to do that.

Comment: @AMonty I updated the answer to use the DATEADD function that is more universal.